# Spilt one object observable into two by extracting with custom map

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2, reactivex

I have List of object List data as observable which includes two child List , List. I want to extract and process them separately.

```
    CustomMapper mapper = new CustomMapper(parentList).

    object1List=mapper.getObject1List();
    object2List=mapper.getObject2List();
    object1Observable.subscribe();
    object2Observable.subscribe();
```

Comment: `share()` their common parent and subscribe to it with two separate streams? Also, what is the relevance of the code in your example?

Comment: check the [groupBy](https://proandroiddev.com/exploring-rxjava-in-android-operators-for-transforming-observables-367c22d86677#3e92) operator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve similar result with `share()` Operator

```java
 Observable o = Observable.just(1,2,"one","two",3,"four").share();
        o.filter(item -> item instanceof String)
              .map((Function<Object, String>) o1 -> o1.toString())
                .subscribe(o1 -> System.out.println("String is "+o1));

        o.filter(item -> item instanceof Integer)
                .map((Function<Object, Integer>) o1 -> ((Integer) o1))
                .subscribe(o1 -> System.out.println("Integer is "+o1));
```

result is:

```
String is one
String is two
String is four
Integer is 1
Integer is 2
Integer is 3
```

More info : https://medium.com/mindorks/how-to-use-rxjava-share-operator-26b08973771a